# Selenium: How to input text on a custom textfield?

Tags: javascript, selenium

So I have this text fields as show on the picture.

[image]

My question is how can I write on this kind of textfield.

I tried `sendKeys` for example on `Employer SSN` but it doesn't input anything. Even clearing on that textfield before writing anything still wont write anything. I think the event on that textfield is preventing me from writing anything using `sendKeys`

For the date fields I tried `sendKeys('12/12/2003')`. But the character automatically jump to the year after writing '12/' escaping the  day (which is middle part). The same with the Employer SSN field I think the event on this date field is preventing me from doing what I want.

Is there any better approach to this than by using `sendKeys`
Do you have idea how can we do it with javascript inside selenium?

UPDATE:

This is the html structure for
Employer SSN

`<input name="ctl00$MainContent$txtSearchByEmployeeSSN" type="text" id="ctl00_MainContent_txtSearchByEmployeeSSN" class="txtStandard" style="border: 1px solid rgb(168, 168, 168);">`

Date Field

`<input name="ctl00$MainContent$txtSearchByStartingCertificateDate" type="text" value="6/22/2021 12:00:00 AM" id="ctl00_MainContent_txtSearchByStartingCertificateDate" class="txtStandard hasDatepicker" data-datepicker="true" style="border: 1px solid rgb(168, 168, 168);">`

here is the page source

https://gist.github.com/flashery/7443e6837bfd076bd055dd37b1241f1e

Comment: Can you share the html? Also did you try to set the value through javascript?

Comment: We need to see your HTML and Page URL if it's public, then share the code what you have tried and we'd be happy to help you

Comment: @cruisepandey  its not a public url. Can I share the page source?

Comment: @itronic1990 I added the html input field on my question

Comment: yes please share

Comment: @cruisepandey updated the question with my gist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution

```
await driver.executeScript(
        "document.querySelector(\"input[name='ctl00$MainContent$txtSearchByEmployerFEIN']\").value = 123123123;"
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

For **Employee SSN field :**

try the below xpath :

```
//label[contains(text(), 'Employee SSN:')]/following-sibling::input
```

and use it like this :

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//label[contains(text(), 'Employee SSN:')]/following-sibling::input")).sendKeys("some value");
```

**Update :**

```
await driver.findElement(By.xpath("//label[contains(text(), 'Employee SSN:')]/following-sibling::input"));.sendKeys('some value');
```

Comment: The same it is not writing anything

Comment: Do you have idea how can we do it with javascript inside selenium?

Comment: Your binding language is JavaScript or Java ?

Comment: JavaScript bindings with chrome driver

Comment: I found something on internet, Check it out in update code section

Comment: Did you change this line `await driver.findElement(By.name('q'));.sendKeys('webdriver', Key.RETURN);` to `await driver.findElement(By.xpath("//label[contains(text(), 'Employee SSN:')]/following-sibling::input"));.sendKeys('some value');` and still it did not work ?

Comment: I already find a solution using driver.executeScript. Read my answer below thank you so much man.